# SetState Is Not A Function and the "bind" has been made

Tags: reactjs

I have an input that has an onChange. It is situated on the login, which has a password input and a submit button. Quite simple, and it works well (I tracked it in the console).Here's the code:

```
...

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
      loginMode: true, 
      error: this.props.loginU.errorEmailMsg == null 
     }
    this.handleEmailError = this.handleEmailError.bind(this);
  }

...

<Field
    component={Input}
    type="email"
    name="email"
    required={true}
    onChange={this.handleEmailError}
    errorState={ this.state.error == true && this.props.loginU.errorEmailMsg != null || this.props.loginU.errorMsg != null ? true : false }
        />
```

The problem occurs when I submit it, giving me the error of `TypeError: this.setState is not a function`. And the error targets a function named onSubmit, that doesn't need a bind, and I think is not important for the problem because it all works when I remove the "handleEmailError". Maybe this is a problem of lifecycle or someting like this, I really don't get it. Can you show me when I have the mistake?
Here's how I call the onSubmit:

```
    if (showLogin) {  

      form = <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(v => this.onSubmit(v))}>
          <Field
              component={Input}
              type="email"
              name="email"
              required={true}
              onChange={this.handleEmailError}
              errorState={ this.state.error == true && this.props.loginU.errorEmailMsg != null || this.props.loginU.errorMsg != null ? true : false }
            />

...
```

Comment: Need more info can you please put your code on stackblitz. if not then share whole component ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because `handleSubmit` returns a function, you don't explicitly set the context of the returning function, therefore it gets invoked in the context of the DOM component i.e `form`

To give you an example, the following should work

```
 onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(v => this.onSubmit(v))(e)}
```

That's because we are using arrow functions to switch the handler context, and the internal arrow function inherits this context.

<strike>If you declare `handleSubmit` as a class field, you automatically bind to the context of the component and your code should work as is</strike>

```
handleSubmit = func => {
  ...
}
```

Given you've now confirmed `handleSubmit` is passed in as a prop, then the simplest approach here is to bind it before you assign the handler e.g.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.submitHandler = this.props.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
...
<form onSubmit={this.submitHandler(v => this.onSubmit(v))}>
```

Comment: Hi @James, thank you for the answer... but I can't get it enough. I understood the first part of the explication but no the second. Even so, I've tried the code. The error doesn't appear anymore... but I can't submit.

Comment: @PedroRelvas you'd need to debug your code, if the issue is gone then the problem is fixed. If something else is now broken as a result then you'll need to share a small example demonstrating the problem, not much I can do at this point without seeing the code / problem.

Comment: @PedroRelvas I forgot to invoke the function returned by `handleSubmit` in the first example, sorry (I have updated). However, as explained in the later part, if you leverage class fields your original code should just work.

Comment: my handleSubmit is a const... const { handleSubmit } = this.props ... and not a function. I'm a begginer btw, so that's because I can't get it at 100%:

Comment: @PedroRelvas no problem, and thanks for confirming. Please see update